# Why does four ttyUSB entries appear when I plug one mobile broadband modem?

Tags: usb, mobile-broadband

I am using D-Link DWP-156 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I plug it into  one of the four USB ports on my laptop, 4 new devices are detected by `/dev` folder viz: `ttyUSB0`, `ttyUSB1`, `ttyUSB2` and `ttyUSB3`. Why is this happening when I plug one device? Is it okay or is that a problem?

I can use the modem with no problems. I just want to know whether this behavior of `/dev` is ok or not.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to enter this in the terminal:

```
     gedit /etc/fstab
```

and at the bottom of the file type this in:

```
     none     usb ttyusb0     errors=noremount-usb     1
     none     usb ttyusb1     errors=noremount-usb     1
     none     usb ttyusb2     errors=noremount-usb     1
     none     usb ttyusb3     errors=noremount-usb     1
```

and it might work fine this way when it is rebooted.

Comment: The questioner asked whether it's alright and expected that one physical device appears as four devices in software, which this doesn't actually answer at all.

Comment: Have you then tryed this:  none        usb ttyusb0   usb ttyusb1     usb ttyusb2     usb ttyusb3     errors=noremount-ro       1